# SQL Server Profiler needs too much memory

Tags: sql, database, trace, sql-server-profiler

I'm using SQL Server Profiler for recording the activity of an software, which creates a ~50 GByte database with > 300 tables including the data. The Profiler saves the trace log into a table in a second database, which will be used for analysis later.

But, there is a problem with the memory usage of the SQL Server Profiler, because the application displays ALL (!) Traces in a table of the interface. As an result, the application needs more than 3 GByte after a few minutes. I don't have more than 50 GByte memory!

Is there a way to disable this table and only log into a table in the database? Also a command line tool which is able to record the same information would be great.

Answer (score 2):

There are a whole load of stored procedures/functions, etc, for creating traces, without using the SQL Server profiler UI. There are too many to list them all here, but the root of the documentation is [Introducing SQL Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191006.aspx). You should hopefully be able to find the right combination to call to get the trace you want.

These server-side traces have to be stored to file, rather than into another table, but you can always import them into a table later if you need them there for analysis.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to use these stored procedures, because it would result in creating and importing a > 50 GByte file. (I think the trace will become much more than 100 GB.) I hope there is enough coffee here for today, or another solution. :-(

Comment: @DiableNoir - You can set a maximum file size for the trace and have it roll over to a new file when that size is reached. Profiler uses the rowset trace provider. This is also used (I assume) by `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace` if you want to create a custom application to do this though.